# jQueryUI and SlidesJS conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, conflict

I cant get out from what seems to be a simple conflict problem. I got a page using, **jquery.1.8**, **jquery-ui.1.8.20**, and pretty nice plugin for slideshows and carousel called **SlidesJs** (http://slidesjs.com).

Having both jQueryUI and SlidesJs loaded in the same page make slidesJS losing is slide transition effect animation (while moving from a slide to another). Everything working fine but this. I have my slides switching without the animation, anyway the speed of the sliding animation is keeped (my milliseconds are correctly waited before slide switch). Other transition effects like "fade" work fine.
I tried to add the jquery.easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and explicitly use some easing effect but nothing changed.

This is my init configuration for SlidesJS.

```
    $(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        generateNextPrev: false, //Default is false
        container: 'slides_container', //Default is "slides_container"
        pagination: true, //if slider use pagination, Default is TRUE
        generatePagination: true,
        slideSpeed: 250,
        effect: 'slide, fade',              
        preloadImage: '../images/loading.gif',              
        play: 0,
    });
});
```

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure what's happening. If I leave out the call to jQuery(".slides").slides() and run it from the console instead, everything works fine.

Comment: My transitions stopped working when I upgraded jQuery from 1.7.1 to 1.8.3.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove divs around your images.

http://slidesjs.com/#docs

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like a charm. Who would've thought.

Answer (score 0):

Open slides.jquery.js and find line 98 and 99

Find:

```
    position = width*2;
    direction = -width*2;
```

```
Replace:
```

```
    position = option.width*2;
    direction = -option.width*2;
```